# Update panel to display output from console

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to show the console output from a process started by my webapp. I tried to set it up so that when I receive a line of text, I update the label then reload (update) the update panel, but the panel doesn't seem to update.

I can't figure out why my update panel isn't updating. I print out the console output as it is received, but the update panel doesn't update at all.

```
protected void RunBatch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Process p = new Process();
    p.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\...\test.bat";

    // Set UseShellExecute to false for redirection.
    p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
    p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
    p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

    // Set our event handler to asynchronously read the sort output.
    p.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(OutputReceived);

    // Start the process.
    p.Start();

    // Start the asynchronous read of the sort output stream.
    p.BeginOutputReadLine();
}

protected void OutputReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    Output_lbl.Text += e.Data;
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(Output_lbl.Text); // I see this output
    UpdatePanel1.Update(); // Doesn't update
}
```

.

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="Testing._Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <p>
        <asp:Button ID="RunBatch" runat="server" Text="Run Batch!" 
            onclick="RunBatch_Click" />
    </p>

    <asp:ScriptManager runat="server" />
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" >
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="Output_lbl" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>

</asp:Content>
```

.

EDIT:
I changed the Update Panel's UpdateMode.
I've tried to implement a timer to update the update panel, which it does, but it prints out "1:48:07 PM -- " ... and continues to count without printing any other `Text` even after receiving the debug messages:

```
This is the output from the batch file
This is the output from the batch fileThis is output line 2 from the batch file
This is the output from the batch fileThis is output line 2 from the batch fileThis is output line 3 from the batch file
```

.

```
string Text = "";
protected void OutputReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    Text += e.Data;
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(Text);
}

protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Output_lbl.Text = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString() + " -- " + Text;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your panel doesn't update because you set the UpdateMode to Conditional without specifying any triggers that would cause it to postback to the server asynchronously and fetch the updated content. You would need to embed a Timer in the UpdatePanel and configure that as a trigger for the UpdatePanel. See article [How to refresh update panel with a timer.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc295400.aspx)

Instead of using an update panel, why don't you try using AJAX combined with a web method? UpdatePanels are notoriously difficult to work with.

Edit...
I think you're missing the idea that each request to the webserver is unique, so you need a way to persist the output from the console program between postbacks. Below, I make use of Session.

Code behind

```
protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        Output_lbl.Text+=Session["Text"].ToString();            
                }
protected void OutputReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
    Session["Text"]+=e.Data;
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(Text);
    }
```

The ASPX page.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UpdatePanel1" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="false">
<Triggers>
<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" EventName="Tick" />
</Triggers>
<ContentTemplate>
<asp:Timer runat="server" ID="Timer1" OnTick="Timer1_Tick" Interval="150"  />
<asp:Label ID="Output_lbl" runat="server" />
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```